# Make Safari ignore image exif data

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

Is there a way, html/css/javascript wise to make safari ignore exif image rotation? All my searches ended up with solutions, that tell to strip the EXIF data. Since It would be unfeasible with the current project, I really hope there is a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just stripping the tags from any new images that get added, still would like to know a way to do this browser-side, as stripping tags of a few million images is not really a feasible option, computational power-wise.